# How does playframework distribute request action, reflection?

Tags: java, playframework

I've used both Play1.x and Play2.x, but I didn't find how Play distributes its request to different actions in its source code.

e.g.

`http://HOST:9000/Application/index`

Play could find the controller Application, and then invoke its index method.

I thought Play works this way:

1. Get URI's first part `Application` and init Application using reflection.
2. Get the second part of URI, `index`, invoke `index()` of Application using reflection.

But I don't know where's the code exactly.

And, If it using a lot of reflection, how could it handle millions of request ? I think reflection is a lot of slower than direct method call(Or Play make some magic optimize ?).

Comment: You better invest 20 minutes into reading any tutorial on Play.

Comment: I know how to configure it, but here I want to know how play resolve it .

Comment: Then it's a good question!

Answer (score 1):

Route file get compiled into `target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/routes_routing.scala` file.

Even if reflection would be involved why should it be slow? File need to be reflected once at app startup.

Answer (score 0):

The route file points each uri to a specific method.

For example:

```
GET   /clients/:id          controllers.Clients.show(id: Long)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about routes type-safety incorporated in Play 2.x you can easily write custom resolver which will catch all unhandled routes with [`Dynamic parts spanning several /`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/JavaRouting) so using simple string operations + reflections you can access any controller/action combination you want...

Anyway consider if your app's security is worth of this sacrifice.

PS.: hard believing that samples are not required to this approach, in other case let me know, I'll write something in free time